# Instant transition between site pages

Tags: asp.net-core

Good evening!
There is a requirement to provide the most invisible transition between the pages of the site. There are transition animations, departing blocks are different, pop-up text, and so on. It would be desirable, that at transition to another page there was no this "flicker". The application is written in asp net core 2.0. How to achieve shuster from the site, a good host or Mb have any chips in the code for this?
I don’t really want to rewrite the site to the spa, as it’s a complete zero in this)

Comment: Frome my understanding you wish to go from one page to another without flicker/reload and you don't want to write as SPA?  If so, you could just load the views as partial views using Ajax so when next page is loaded its Ajax call to load the partial view instead of the entire page, keeping your existing code and just adding some jquery.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, thanks! I have already started studying angular to rewrite the whole application again ... It may be worth trying your method.